# Datetimepicker Databinding custom type

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datetimepicker

Currently I have a custom date class that stores the day of the year and year:

```
public class CustomDate
{
    public short Day { get; set; }

    public short Year { get; set; }

    public CustomDate(short day, short year)
    {
        this.Day = day;
        this.Year = year;
    }
}
```

This can be used in a class:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public CustomDate MyDate { get; set; }
}
```

All good so far. Now if want to bind this to a winform datetimetimepicker control I would do something like:

```
    private void BuildDob()
    {
        var bind = new Binding("Value", this._foo, "MyDate", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
        bind.Parse += (s, e) =>
            {
                e.Value = new CustomDate(
                    day: (short)((DateTime)e.Value).DayOfYear,
                    year: (short)((DateTime)e.Value).Year);
            };
        this.dtPickerDateOfBirth.DataBindings.Add(bind);
```

This works correctly in terms of the date picked being parsed and correctly set on the object. The issue I am facing is that the datetimepicker isn't displaying/setting itself to the correct binded date when the form loads, it sets itself to 01/01/1900, I am guessing this is because I am trying to bind to CustomDate which type can't be bound to the datetimepicker.

What solutions do I have to bind to the correct property but have the correct date set when loaded?

Comment: if you create a second property for DateTime, like `public DateTime Date {get=> MyDate; set=> MyDate=value;}` (using implict operador in the answer)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can create an implicit operator to convert your CustomDate type to DateTime and the other way around:

```
public class CustomDate
{
    public int Day { get; set; }

    public int Year { get; set; }

    public CustomDate(int day, int year)
    {
        this.Day = day;
        this.Year = year;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Year + "/" + Day;
    }

    public static implicit operator CustomDate(DateTime _dt) => new CustomDate(_dt.DayOfYear, _dt.Year);
    public static implicit operator DateTime(CustomDate _dt) => new DateTime(_dt.Year,1,1).AddDays(_dt.Day-1);


}
```

the Day and Year properties are integers and not shorts, I don't see why change that...

https://dotnetfiddle.net/wa9eji

Comment: I see what you're getting at but this doesn't effect the binding: this.dtPickerDateOfBirth.DataBindings.Add("Value", this._foo, "MyDate", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged); When the control loads it is still 01/01/1900 regardless

Comment: Sorry, I will remove the answer ... could you customize the DateTimePicker control?